# Overriding errorChannel configured in @MessagingGateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, integration

I have configured **@MessagingGateway** as below to use an error channel, which works as expected.

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "DefaultInboundErrorHandlerChannel")
public interface InboundMessagingGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "InboundEntryChannel")
    void receive(XferRes response);

}
```

Within the flow I am passing the object to a transformer as below:

**Step 1:**

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "InboundEntryChannel", outputChannel = "TransmissionLogChannel")
public CassandraEntity createEntity(
        org.springframework.messaging.Message<XferRes> message) throws ParseException {
    XferRes response = message.getPayload();
    CassandraEntity entity = new CassandraEntity();
    // ... getters & setter ommitted for brevity
    return entity;
}
```

Next, I update the entity as below:
**Step 2:**

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "TransmissionLogChannel", outputChannel="PublishChannel")
public XferRes updateCassandraEntity(
        org.springframework.messaging.Message<XferRes> message) {
    XferRes response = message.getPayload();
    this.cassandraServiceImpl.update(response);
    return response;
}
```

And last, I post to a Kafka topic as below: 
**Step 3:**

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "PublishChannel")
public void publish(org.springframework.messaging.Message<XferRes> message){

        XferRes response = message.getPayload();
        publisher.post(response);       
    }
```

In case of an error I post the message to a service which publishes the error object to log ingestion:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="defaultInboundErrorHandlerChannel")
public void handleInvalidRequest(org.springframework.messaging.Message<MessageHandlingException> message) throws ParseException {
    XferRes originalRequest = (XferRes) message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload();
    this.postToErrorBoard(originalRequest)
}
```

If an error occurs at **Step 2:** in updating the DB, then also I want to invoke **Step 3**. A trivial way is to remove the **Step 2** & make the call to update database from **Step 1**.

Is there any other way in Spring Integration where I can invoke **Step 3** irrespective if an error occurs or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique called `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Since I see that you reuse a payload on the second step to send to the third step, then it is definitely a use-case for the `PublishSubscribeChannel` and two sequential subscribers to it.

I mean you create a `PublishSubscribeChannel` `@Bean` and those `@ServiceActivator`s are use the name to this channel.

More info is in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel). Pay attention to the `ignoreFailures` property:

```
/**
 * Specify whether failures for one or more of the handlers should be
 * ignored. By default this is <code>false</code> meaning that an Exception
 * will be thrown whenever a handler fails. To override this and suppress
 * Exceptions, set the value to <code>true</code>.
 * @param ignoreFailures true if failures should be ignored.
 */
public void setIgnoreFailures(boolean ignoreFailures) {
```